# Display rating on Google search engine

Tags: google-api

My question is about when I search my website name on **Google Search**, how to do this on my website?

[image]

Comment: Huh? You can't just be asking how to do a google search . . . Are you trying to use a `web scraper` to get the google ratings for many businesses? If so, what kind of tool do you want to use? What do you want to do with this data?

Comment: I'm trying to do marketing with my website. Just for SEO thing

Answer (score 0):

If you use WordPress; you can use [WP-POSTRATINGS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/) plugin, which is a very easy plugin to enable rating for articles, and it will show the total rating in google results.

Or if you're not using CMS, read this crash tutorial about adding stars: https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/seo/how-to-get-stars-search/

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna check this one!